# Imbalanced data set for a regression problem

Tags: regression, imbalanced-data

I am working on a regression problem in which my data set is imbalanced in different categories like this question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/387499/which-is-the-right-way-to-handle-imbalanced-data-in-a-regression-problem?newreg=327638891c3342149d33089f01b7e51e

Now my question is that how we can solve this problem? My target (output variable) has a normal distribution and the only problem is the distribution in categories. Except weighting MSE is there any other solution?